# Building the Kernel: make modules_install gives undefined symbol

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am getting the follow errors when I do a make modules_install:

```
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/3.14.36/updates/vboxsf.ko needs unknown symbol __stack_chk_fail
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/3.14.36/updates/vboxsf.ko needs unknown symbol contig_page_data
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/3.14.36/updates/vboxguest.ko needs unknown symbol __stack_chk_fail
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/3.14.36/updates/vboxguest.ko needs unknown symbol contig_page_data
jcp linux14 # modinfo -n vboxsf.ko
modinfo: ERROR: Module vboxsf.ko not found.
jcp linux14 # modinfo -n vboxsf
modinfo: ERROR: Module vboxsf not found.
```

The vb*.ko modules aren't visible to modinfo or depmod so I'm not sure how to find the dependencies.

Once the dependencies are found, how do I know which options to turn on in menuconfig and where to find them in the menu system?

Background:
I'm running Linux Mint (Cinnamon/Qiana) as a VM on VMware Player (host OS --> Windows7) and a 3.19.1 kernel.  The 3.19 kernel compiled with "'struct file' has no member named 'f_dentry' so I am trying to revert to an older version of the kernel -- 3.14.36.  I want to make my kernel as small as possible because the full kernel with the default menuconfig .config takes 1.5 hours to compile on my VM.  (I have an assignment to add a system call to the kernel so right now I'm trying to make a small, error-free kernel to work with).

I created my .config file with 'make localmodconfig'

"make bzImage" and "make modules" both executed without errors.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Jenny

Comment: I think that you may be mixing the running kernel and the compiled one... If `uname -r` returns anything other than 3.14.36 you may need to use the `modinfo -k` option.

Comment: Thanks --  The "modinfo -k" option worked to find the modules.